# I've deployed a rails/boostrap site to a new domain. Random bootstrap features aren't working. Looking for debugging strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I could put code but it seems antithetical to the point. Imagine if you will, a div class="panel-group" id="accordion" that is:

- Fully functional on domain A
- On domain B, the accordion sections won't open

How would one go about debugging such a thing? It seems I missed some step related to Bootstrap when I deployed but I haven't been able to find anything relevant.

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#101010;color:#D0D0D8">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#featured">
                    Featured ★★★★★</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="featured" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" style="background-color:#101010;color:#D0D0D8">  <br>
```

...
...
...

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the javascript portion of it maybe? do you have any JS error in the browser's console?

Comment: Excellent, this leads me to a Javascript error and a stack trace that isn't immediately helpful (TypeError: No default value (anonymous function) -- collapse.js), but more information than I had a moment ago. Still digging and thanks!

Comment: Check your logs on the broken domain. Looks like there was a precompile JS error.

Answer (score 0):

In the process of touching and upgrading dependencies, updated jquery to 3.5.0 and things started working. Not a satisfying answer, but the site is now working...